# PHP Define table.Field name

Tags: php

I have a query like this:

Normally is a Select goes like this:

```
SELECT username ...
```

I would set a variable to it like this:

```
$username = $row['username'];
```

My problem is that it's like this:

```
SELECT a.username, ...
```

So I've tried:

```
$username = $row['a.username'];
```

But this does not work .. How is the right way to do this in this case?

Comment: The same way, `$row['username']`.

Comment: `var_dump($row);` to find out... (but it's still `$row['username']`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
"SELECT a.username, ... WHERE a.username = '" . $row['username'] .'";
```

Thats SQL syntax day 1. Have a good look at the [Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html)